# How to draw a double head arrow between two points with label

Tags: math-mode, tikz-arrows

I want to draw an arrow like this `<---d--->`, alongside a line going from x to y.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Something like `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (0,0) -- ++ (2,0) node[midway,fill=white]{label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`?

Comment: @marmot Yes that works. Thank you. Is drawing alongside, say the line `(0,0 --(2,0)`, as easy as changing the arrow to `(0,1)--(2,1)` to draw one unit above?

Comment: It depends on whether you have other elements in the picture. If you have no other elements, then the absolute coordinates do not play a role, if you do, you shift relative to these other objects.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Can you add an screenshot and mark there what you want to change? That would make your question clearer ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from marmot was :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0.5) -- (2,0.5);
    \draw[latex-latex] (0,0) -- ++ (2,0) node[midway,fill=white]{label};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I have a crudely extended this into a command for parameterized use:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
...
\newcommand{\doublearrowlabel}[5]{
    % accepts a start point, end point, spacing, gradient and label
    \path let \p1=#1 in coordinate (start) at ({\x1 + #3* cos(#4)},{\y1-#3 * sin(#4)});
    \path let \p2=#2 in coordinate (end) at ({\x2 + #3* cos(#4)},{\y2-#3 * sin(#4)});

    \draw[latex-latex]  (start) -- (end) node[midway,fill=white]{#5};
}
...
\draw [->](-0.5,0.8) -- (1,1);
\doublearrowlabel{(-0.5, 0.8)}{(1, 1)}{-5}{75}{First}

\draw [->](-0.5,0.2) -- (-0.8,0.6);
\doublearrowlabel{(-0.5, 0.2)}{(-0.8, 0.6)}{5}{0}{Second}

\draw [->](0.0,-0.3) -- (0.6, 0.3);
\doublearrowlabel{(0.0,-0.3)}{(0.6, 0.3)}{5}{45}{Third}

\draw [->] (0.6, -0.3) -- (0.0,-0.6);
\doublearrowlabel{(0.6, -0.3)}{(0.0,-0.6)}{5}{65}{Fourth}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply in **math-mode** you could use the simple code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\longleftarrow \mathrm{label}\longrightarrow $
\end{document}
```

It is possible to use, for example, also as tikz-arrows the `tikz-cd` package, you can obtained the desidered output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm]
{} \arrow[r, "\text{label}" description, leftrightarrow] & {}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm]
{} \arrow[d, "\text{label}" description, leftrightarrow]\\
{}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, column sep=2cm]
{} & \\
   & {} \arrow[lu, "\text{label}" description, leftrightarrow]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```